# Separate a number into fixed part

Tags: math

What is the algorithm to find the number way to separate number M to p part and no two part equal.
Example: 
M = 5, P = 2
they are (1,4) (2,3). If P = 3 then no partition availabe, i.e
not (1,2,2) because there two 2 in partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the expanded product

> (1+x)(1+x<sup>2</sup>)(1+x<sup>3</sup>)...(1+x<sup>n</sup>)

find the coefficient of x^n. This gives the number of any possibility to represent n as sum of different numbers, i.e., a variable number of terms.

---

You want the number of possibilites to have

> n = i<sub>1</sub>+i<sub>2</sub>+...+i<sub>P</sub> with i<sub>1</sub> < i<sub>2</sub> < ... < i<sub>P</sub>

which can be realized by setting

> i<sub>1</sub>=j<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>=i<sub>1</sub>+j<sub>2</sub>=j<sub>1</sub>+j<sub>2</sub>, ...
>
> i<sub>P</sub>=i<sub>P-1</sub>+j<sub>P</sub>=j<sub>1</sub>+j<sub>2</sub>+...+j<sub>P</sub> with all j<sub>k</sub> > 0

so that the original task is the same as counting all the ways that one can solve

> n = P * j<sub>1</sub>+(P-1) * j<sub>2</sub>+...+1 * j<sub>P</sub>  with all j<sub>k</sub> > 0, but unrelated among each other.

The corresponding generator function is the product of the geometric series of the powers of x, omitting the constant term,

> (x+x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>3</sup>+...) * (x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>4</sup>+x<sup>6</sup>+...) * (x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>6</sup>+x<sup>9</sup>+...) * ... * (x<sup>P</sup>+x<sup>2*P</sup>+x<sup>3*P</sup>+...)
>
> = x<sup>P*(P+1)/2</sup> * (1+x+x<sup>2</sup>+...) * (1+x<sup>2</sup>+x<sup>4</sup>+...) * (1+x<sup>3</sup>+x<sup>6</sup>+...) * ... * (1+x<sup>P</sup>+x<sup>2*P</sup>+...)

Clearly, one needs n >= P*(P+1)/2 to get any solution at all. For P=3 that bound is n >= 6, so that n=5 has indeed no solutions in that case.

---

Algorithm

```
count = new double[N]
for k=0..N-1 do count[k] = 1
for j=2..P do
    for k=j..N-1 do
        count[k] += count[k-j]
```

Then count[k] contains the number of combinations for n=P*(P+1)/2+k.

Comment: Do you get any algorithm for this? Please share it, I'm not good at math.

Comment: This generating function is for number of all possible partitions of n into distinct parts, not only into p distinct parts

Comment: Thanks, this was not entirely clear from the formulation of the problem. Added the reduction and generating function for the sum of P different terms.

Comment: Generating formula for this task is `x^(p*(p+1)/2) / Product{k=1..p}(1-x^k)` - don't know how to expand this rational to polynomial in general case

Comment: One factor at a time. Polynomial division by binomials is a rather elementary algorithm, see for instance the Horner-Ruffini scheme.